# How do I hook a gdb pretty-printer without shared library?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, nim-lang

All documentation I found about writing gdb pretty printers is basically this one site: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter.html#Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter.

It tells me that the pretty printers are loaded when a shared library is loaded.

But I do not have a shared library, one could say my library is header only. I want to write a pretty printer for a NimStringDesc for the programming language Nim. It compiles to C, so here are all relevant parts that get generated into the c file.

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(_MSC_VER)
#  define SEQ_DECL_SIZE /* empty is correct! */
#else
#  define SEQ_DECL_SIZE 1000000
#endif
typedef char NIM_CHAR;
typedef long long int NI64;
typedef NI64 NI;
struct TGenericSeq {NI len; NI reserved; };
struct NimStringDesc {TGenericSeq Sup; NIM_CHAR data[SEQ_DECL_SIZE]; };
```

here are the loaded libraries of the test program that I wrote:

```
ldd nim-debug-test
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffed8052000)
libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f4f1bf8e000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4f1bbed000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4f1c192000)
```

So I cannot use something like `/home/user/gdb/nim-gdb.py`, because there is no libnim that gets loaded. So what do I have to do, that this file get's loaded anyway?

EDIT:

nim creates several c files that then get compiled and linked together with a normal c linker. These are the files generated by the nim compiler:

```
~/proj/nim-debug-test/nimcache/ ls
nim_debug_test_foobar.c  stdlib_os.o          stdlib_posix.c     stdlib_strutils.o  stdlib_times.c
nim_debug_test_foobar.o  stdlib_parseutils.c  stdlib_posix.o     stdlib_system.c    stdlib_times.o
stdlib_os.c              stdlib_parseutils.o  stdlib_strutils.c  stdlib_system.o
```

I know that stdlib_system is automatically imported into every nim project, so I can say, that when the objectfile `stdlib_system.o` get's loaded, it is a nim project.

I have one gdb init script:

```
~/gdb/ ls
stdlib_system-gdb.py
```

But it does not get loaded. This is the content of stdlib_system-gdb.py:

```
class NimStringPrinter(object):
    "Print a Nim string"

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def to_string(self):
        return self.val['data']

    def display_hint(self):
        return 'string'

def string_lookup_function(val):
    lookup_tag = val.type.tag

    if lookup_tag == None:
        return None

    regex = re.compile("^NimStringDesc$")

    if regex.match(lookup_tag):
        return StdStringPrinter(val)

    return None

def register_printers(objfile):
    objfile.pretty_printers.append(string_lookup_function)
```

Here Is some gdb output:

```
~/proj/nim_debug_test/ gdb nim_debug_test 
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.11
[...]
Reading symbols from nim_debug_test...done.
(gdb) info auto-load 
gdb-scripts:  No auto-load scripts.
guile-scripts:  No auto-load scripts.
libthread-db:  No auto-loaded libthread-db.
local-gdbinit:  Local .gdbinit file was not found.
python-scripts:  No auto-load scripts.
(gdb) show auto-load
gdb-scripts:  Auto-loading of canned sequences of commands scripts is on.
guile-scripts:  Auto-loading of Guile scripts is on.
libthread-db:  Auto-loading of inferior specific libthread_db is on.
local-gdbinit:  Auto-loading of .gdbinit script from current directory is on.
python-scripts:  Auto-loading of Python scripts is on.
safe-path:  List of directories from which it is safe to auto-load files is $debugdir:$datadir/auto-load.
scripts-directory:  List of directories from which to load auto-loaded scripts is $debugdir:$datadir/auto-load.
(gdb) info pretty-printer 
global pretty-printers:
  builtin
    mpx_bound128
(gdb)
```

The problem is, I don't know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The document really should say `objfile`. Executables and shared libraries are handled exactly the same, except that shared libraries can be `dlopen`ed so in that case the script can be called later.

In either case, simply create a file named `$objfile-gdb.py`; that code will be executed whenever the objfile is loaded. That script can either, or you may prepend one of the debug roots to the full path (typically `/usr/share/gdb/auto-load` and `/usr/lib/debug`).

Note that there are some infelicities regarding if an objfile is loaded **more than once** (typically if you restart the application using `run` - I have not tested if this also occurs with a `dlopen`-`dlclose`-`dlopen` sequence), or if you use split debuginfo (since that counts as a separate objfile but uses the same script).

I have some vague thoughts regarding a virtual python package with a custom `__path__` that changes on every execution that could solve this ...

Comment: I added now much more information to my project, but the problem is, that I don't know how I should call my pyton script, so that gdb actually tries to open it. I can't even find a list of opened libraries that contains anything like `stdlib_system.o`. I hope you can help me furthe with the additional information I just added.

Comment: If your executable is called `nim-debug-test`, your script needs to be called `nim-debug-test-gdb.py`

Comment: Ok at least it works now so far, that It tells me that I have to set an auto-load safe path. So the question is, where is the auto-load safe path, which is currently `$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load`. But what is $debugdir and $datadir. What values do they have, how do I look up their values?

Comment: Those are the two paths I mentioned earlier, typically `/usr/lib/debug` and `/usr/share/gdb/auto-load`. If you want to work on stuff for development, add `/home/foo/src` or whatever. If you want it to work for deploy, you should set up splitdebug and such.